# How to keep asking for permission in Flutter

Tags: flutter, permissions, location

So I have an app that requires **location** to function, currently I am handling permissions using [geolocator](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator), but so far I can only show an alert dialog to open app settings when users denied the permission. Is there a way to keep re-asking for permission if the status is PermissionStatus.denied until they finally allows it or permanently denied it?

My codes (which are pretty much similar to the package's README):

```
  Future<Position> _determinePosition() async {
    LocationPermission permission;

    permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();
    if (permission == LocationPermission.deniedForever) {
      showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) => CupertinoAlertDialog(
                title: Text(
                    AppLocalizations.of(context).applyPermissionNotGranted),
                content:
                    Text(AppLocalizations.of(context).applyPermissionLocation),
                actions: <Widget>[
                  CupertinoDialogAction(
                    child: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context).applyOpenSettings),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                      openAppSettings();
                    },
                  )
                ],
              ));
      return Future.error(
          'Location permissions are permantly denied, we cannot request permissions.');
    }
    if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
      permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
      if (permission != LocationPermission.whileInUse &&
          permission != LocationPermission.always) {
        return Future.error(
            'Location permissions are denied (actual value: $permission).');
      }
    }
    return await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition();
  }
```

Comment: well as much as I know there is not way to reask permisiion if the user denies the permisssion 2 times continourly , the only way around is to ask to allow the permission maually through the app settings.

Comment: @basudevnayak even recursive function is not possible?

Comment: I don't think it is , well I am on it trying to find an answer :)

Comment: This came from the permission handler package's README : if (await Permission.speech.isPermanentlyDenied) {
  // The user opted to never again see the permission request dialog for this
  // app. The only way to change the permission's status now is to let the
  // user manually enable it in the system settings.
  openAppSettings();
}